Why is my Page.DataContext class not found?
im very new to c# and play around something. Now i want to use Models for  my Data Handling so but my class is not found. Do you have any suggestion to get it to run?
Fehler XLS0414 Typ 'vm:MyAppViewModel' wurde nicht gefunden. Stellen Sie sicher, dass keine Assemblyreferenz fehlt, und dass alle referenzierten Assemblys erstellt wurden.    C:\Users\User\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp\Views\MyApp.xaml 17   
MyPage.xaml
xmlns:vm="using:MyApp.ViewModels"

<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MyAppViewModel />
</Page.DataContext>

MyPage.xaml.cs
public sealed partial class MyPage : Page
{

    public MyPage() => InitializeComponent();

    public MyAppViewModel DataContext
    {
        get =>
            (MyAppViewModel)(
            base.DataContext ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("DataContext is not set.")
        );
        set => base.DataContext = value;
    }
}

Where is the error in my namespaces and/or declarations?
/ViewModels
namespace MyApp.ViewModels;

public partial class MyAppViewModel : ObservableRecipient


What are you using for your database?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/datacontext-methods-o-r-designer?view=vs-2022

No Database, the data comes from an api request

Then the API is the database or calls a backend Database.  The model has to match the types in the database.

I tested the code in a blank project. But I can't reproduce this behavior.  Maybe you need to check the name of all the classes like Andrew said since the error says the project can't find the class.

If that is not the case, you might share more code details about the project.

Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information?

I found out whats going wrong here. I get it to work after some hours of searching. I answer my question later so that some other people get this informations too.

Glad to hear that. It is appreciated to share your solution here.

After a long search, I have now found the solution. Firstly, it would have been good for you if the app had been created with the Template Studio and additionally used the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm package. Therefore, I had to take the following steps to address the ViewModel.
App.xaml.cs
InitializeComponent();

Host = Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.
CreateDefaultBuilder().
UseContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory).
ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
{
    // View and ViewModel added
    services.AddTransient<DownloadViewModel>();
    services.AddTransient<DownloadPage>();
}

Services/PageService.cs
public PageService()
{
    //Model and Page added
    Configure<DownloadViewModel, DownloadPage>();
    
}

Now the DownloadPage.xaml.cs
public sealed partial class DownloadPage : Page
{
    public DownloadViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get;
    }

    public DownloadPage()
    {
        ViewModel = App.GetService<DownloadViewModel>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

After these steps, the model is available in my View and Bindings works perfect.
If you have the same problem where bindings don't work or the model isn't found, check if the model is correctly registered and the namespaces are correct.
The example refers to a standard app that was created and preconfigured with Template Studio.
Template Studio: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WASTeamAccount.WindowsTemplateStudio
MVVM Toolkit: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/
